# Reading Space Delimited Strings Line by Line and Storing Them in Arrays (in C)

Tags: c

I have an input file consisting of:

```
CREATEHALL "Red-Hall" "StarDust" 24 20
CREATEHALL "Orange-Hall" "Last_Samurai" 10 20
```

And I want to store each line in an array for future uses.

**So far my code is:**
(Added lots of printf's for debugging purposes.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct str
{
char *commands[5];
};

struct str a[];
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char *token;
    printf("Starting the program...\n");
    char filename[] = "input.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );

    if (file != NULL) {
        char line [1000];
        printf("Read a new line...\n");
        while(fgets(line,sizeof line,file)!= NULL) /* read a line from a file */ {
            j=0;
            printf("%s\n",line);
            printf("Start token stuff...\n");
            /* get the first token */
            token = strtok(line, " ");

            /* walk through other tokens */
            while( token != NULL )
            {
                a[i].commands[j]=token;
                printf( "Stored Command : %s\n", token );
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }

        fclose(file);
    }
    else {
        perror(filename); //print the error message on stderr.
    }
    printf("Finished processing tokens...\n\n\n");

    printf("%s\n%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", a[0].commands[0], a[0].commands[1],a[0].commands[2],a[0].commands[3],a[0].commands[4]);
    printf("%s\n%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", a[1].commands[0], a[1].commands[1],a[1].commands[2],a[1].commands[3],a[1].commands[4]);
    return 0;
}
```

**The output I get on the console is this:**

```
Starting the program...
Read a new line...
CREATEHALL "Red-Hall" "StarDust" 24 20

Start token stuff...
Stored Command : CREATEHALL
Stored Command : "Red-Hall"
Stored Command : "StarDust"
Stored Command : 24
Stored Command : 20

CREATEHALL "Orange-Hall" "Last_Samurai" 10 20
Start token stuff...
Stored Command : CREATEHALL
Stored Command : "Orange-Hall"
Stored Command : "Last_Samurai"
Stored Command : 10
Stored Command : 20
Finished processing tokens...


CREATEHALL
"Orange-Hall"   l"      murai"  ai"
CREATEHALL
"Orange-Hall"   "Last_Samurai"  10      20
```

I'm not very good with C, (this is a very small part of an assignment) but I believe the error is in the

```
a[i].commands[j]=token;
```

line, since before that it reads the words fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) to do so

Comment: for the commands[5] array you need to allocate space for every element. use malloc, and then strcpy to copy the string, don't use value assignment

Comment: Instead of adding lots of printfs for debugging you should consider to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the Man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)

> **Return Value**
>
> The strtok() and strtok_r() functions return a pointer to the next token, or NULL if there are no more tokens.

So pointers you are storing are addresses of `char lib[1000]`, that, at the end of your process, will contain the last line read.

---

Take also note that you defined a bad array, without dimension:

```
struct str a[];
```

should be, at least,

```
struct str a[2];
```

---

The fastest correction can be:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct str
{
char *commands[5];
};

struct str a[2];
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char *token;
    printf("Starting the program...\n");
    char filename[] = "input.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );

    if (file != NULL) {
        char line [1000];
        printf("Read a new line...\n");
        while(fgets(line,sizeof line,file)!= NULL) /* read a line from a file */ {
            j=0;
            printf("%s\n",line);
            printf("Start token stuff...\n");
            /* get the first token */
            token = strtok(line, " ");

            /* walk through other tokens */
            while( token != NULL )
            {
                char *temp = strdup(token);
                if (temp != NULL)
                {
                    a[i].commands[j]=temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "No memory available to store string\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                printf( "Stored Command : %s\n", token );
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }

        fclose(file);
    }
    else {
        perror(filename); //print the error message on stderr.
    }
    printf("Finished processing tokens...\n\n\n");

    printf("%s\n%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", a[0].commands[0], a[0].commands[1],a[0].commands[2],a[0].commands[3],a[0].commands[4]);
    printf("%s\n%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", a[1].commands[0], a[1].commands[1],a[1].commands[2],a[1].commands[3],a[1].commands[4]);
    return 0;
}
```

In more complex project, duplicated strings must be `free`d due to heap allocation performed by `strdup`.

---

Another solution can be implemented using [malloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and allocating space for each element and using [strcpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to copy the token.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct str
{
    char *commands[5];
};

struct str a[2];

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char *token;
    printf("Starting the program...\n");
    char filename[] = "input.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );

    if (file != NULL) {
        char line [1000];
        printf("Read a new line...\n");
        while(fgets(line,sizeof line,file)!= NULL) /* read a line from a file */ {
            j=0;
            printf("%s\n",line);
            printf("Start token stuff...\n");
            /* get the first token */
            token = strtok(line, " ");

            /* walk through other tokens */
            while( token != NULL )
            {
                a[i].commands[j] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
                if (a[i].commands[j] != NULL)
                {
                    strcpy(a[i].commands[j], token);
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "No memory available to store string\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                printf( "Stored Command : %s\n", token );
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }

        fclose(file);
    }
    else {
        perror(filename); //print the error message on stderr.
    }
    printf("Finished processing tokens...\n\n\n");

    printf("%s\n%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", a[0].commands[0], a[0].commands[1],a[0].commands[2],a[0].commands[3],a[0].commands[4]);
    printf("%s\n%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", a[1].commands[0], a[1].commands[1],a[1].commands[2],a[1].commands[3],a[1].commands[4]);
    return 0;
}
```

Same thing here, you should `free`d `malloc`ated memory.

Comment: why setting `struct str a[1];` instead of suggested `struct str a[2];` ?

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As @LPs suggests, just add a strdup() call to keep the extracted string when storing in your array. But before, be sure that you have allocated your struct str a[];

Step1 replace:

```
struct str a[];
```

by:

```
#define MAX_NB_LINES (100)
struct str a[MAX_NB_LINES];
```

Step2 add a strdup() when storing in the array:

```
while( token != NULL )
{
    a[i].commands[j]=strdup(token);
    printf( "Stored Command : %s\n", token );
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    j++;
    if (j >= 5) break; // stop extraction when 5 commands are stored
}
```

> Before starting to use struct str a[], initialize char pointer to
>   NULL.

```
for(i=0;i<MAX_NB_LINES;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
        a[i].commands[j]=NULL;
    }
}
```

> After using the struct str a[], simply free the allocated memory.

```
for(i=0;i<MAX_NB_LINES;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
        // free only the allocated char pointer
        if (a[i].commands[j]!=NULL) free(a[i].commands[j]);
        a[i].commands[j]=NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: And since `strdup` calls `malloc`, what else do you need to be responsible for to prevent memory leaks? Nothing wrong with dynamic allocations, but if the data is of a known max size (e.g. each `command` `16-char` or less, using static arrays in `struct str` would be another option -- tailored to the learning level)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin answer updated